# Can I rearrange the "unpinned" apps on the Dash / Ubuntu Dock?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, 18.10

I'm using Ubuntu 18.10 and the default Dash (or Ubuntu dock). My hobby is don't pin ("Add to Favorites") any app to the Dash, because it's cleaner for me.

Sometime when there're some running apps, I want to rearrange them. Is there any way to do that without pinning ("Add to Favorites") them?